# How do I set the user to be non-root in the Dockerfile (Using base centos image)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Part of my Dockerfile uses the command `USER=root`. What is the name of the default user to swap back to? Or do I have to specify one?

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question please? Contents of Dockerfile / image you're using, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default user for docker images is root. That is, if you don't specify a user using the `USER` command, the instructions gets executed as root.

If you are building on a base image, you need to check the dockerfile for that image to check if there a custom user already created and switch to that. Alternatively, you can check all available users in the docker image by running `RUN cat /etc/passwd`.

You can also create a custom user by running

```
RUN groupadd -g 1000 <group-name> \
    && useradd -d /home/<custome-user> -u 1000 -g 1000 -m -s /bin/bash <username>
USER <username>
```

Answer (score 0):

Default user depends on the base image and defaults to root. For the centos image you are using it is already root.